# what is the meaning of srvid in master.dbo.sysservers?

Tags: sql-server

I working in a shared project

In ASCData database, i have a procedure, but I do not understand the meaning of it

```
set @srvid = -1
SELECT @srvid = srvid FROM master.dbo.sysservers where srvname = 'ASCData_Log'
if(@srvid <> -1)
begin
-- Some insert and select query here
end
```

Please explain help me

why have to compare @srvid ?
and where is master.dbo.sysservers ?

ASCData_Log is one of database of this project.

Answer (score 0):

i don't know ASCData, but i think, it does the following:

1. initialize the variable srvid with "-1" (wich will respresent an error)
2. query the meta-data of the database-server for the server (and the server-id) of the maschine, which holds the ASCData_Log (a log-database)
3. set the server-id to the variable "srvid"
4. begin the procedure if "srvid" not equals "-1" (no error and a server is found)

should be the most logical interpretation...

Comment: Your meaning is, it will check ASCData_Log exist ? if no, @srvid will be '-1' and not excute query below, and if ASCData_Log exist it must have srvid >= 0, and excute query below ?